# Need a specific function in spark which will check whether all elements matches given predicate or not?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I need a function on RDD, let's say 'isAllMatched' which will take a predicate as an argument to match. However, **I don't want to scan all elements, if predicate fails for any element, it should return false. I also want this function to execute parallely on all worker nodes**. Here is the pseudocode:

```
 def isAllMatched[T : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T])(pred: T => Boolean) = {
      foreach(ele <- rdd.elements) {
           if(!pred(ele)) return false;
      }
      return true;
 }
```

Is this possible in Spark ? Is there any built-in function to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know existing RDD operation to achieve this result, but you can implement your function like this:

```
def isAllMatched[T](rdd: RDD[T])(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean =
    rdd.filter(e => !pred(e)).isEmpty
```

Comment: Yes, but this will scan all the elements. I want to break execution as soon as predicate fails.

Answer (score -1):

Piotr's answer is correct. It does exactly what you asked for. Lazy evaluation ensures that the scan stops right-away at the first element failing the predicate test and a boolean false is returned to the driver. Any tasks running on the other nodes on the same operation will be abandoned.